# How to make the white color transparent background?

Tags: css

I want to make the background transparent in white color such that half overlap image on background should match the white color:

Here is my code but doesn't works fine for me

```
background1 {
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

Comment: `background1` I'm gonna guess this should be `.background1` or `#background1`. That's a start.

Comment: try this..background1{ background: rgba (255,255,255, 0.8);}

Comment: Mabye just `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);`

Comment: is `background1` an id or a class? Use `#` or `.` accordingly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use this works fine for me...

```
background1 {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-image: none, linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 10px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.86) 20px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 30px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.94) 40px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.98) 50px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.99) 60px, #FFFFFF 70px);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
div{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block
}
span{
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.60);
   width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:5px;
  color:red;
  padding:5px
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/lanaxepe/2/)**